# How to define column names using 'for loop' inside a class (IsDescription)

Tags: python, pytables

We know that if we need to define the column names of a table using pytables we can do it by the following way:

```
class Project(IsDescription):
    alpha = StringCol(20)
    beta  = StringCol(20) 
    gamma = StringCol(20)
```

where alpha, beta and gamma are the desired column names of the table. 
But suppose I would like to use a list "ColumnNames_list" which contains the column names as follows:
ColumnNames_list[0] = alpha, ColumnNames_list[1] = beta, ColumnNames_list[2] = gamma

Then how should I define the above class "Project"?

I tried with the following:

```
ColumnNames_list = []
ColumnNames_list[0] = alpha 
ColumnNames_list[1] = beta 
ColumnNames_list[2] = gamma

class Project(IsDescription):
    for i in range (0, 10):
        ColumnNames_list[i] = StringCol(20)
```

It's showing the error:

TypeError: Passing an incorrect value to a table column. Expected a Col (or subclass) instance and got: "2". Please make use of the Col(), or descendant, constructor to properly initialize columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few options.  The first (easiest) is to add the attributes *after* you create the class:

```
class Project(IsDescription):
    pass

for name in ColumnNames_List:
    setattr(Project, name, StringCol(20))
```

There are lots of different takes on this one (e.g. you could do it via a class decorator).

The next option is to use the builtin [`type`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type) to construct the class:

```
names = {name: StringCol(20) for name in ColumnNames_List}
Project = type('Project', (IsDescription,), names)
```

The advantage of this approach is that it still works even if some funky metaclass on `IsDescription` requires that the attributes be set at class construction time<sup>1</sup>.  While we're talking about metaclasses ... you *could* use a metaclass to do this, but that is almost certainly overkill.

<sup><sup>1</sup>This is a rare condition but a few popular 3rd party libraries (e.g. `sqlalchemy`) use metaclasses in this way.</sup>

Comment: Awesome! Thanks brother! Your second solution worked perfectly! Have a nice life!